# I am trying to write an abstract data type to represent sets of integer items using linked lists. I am getting a segmentation fault

Tags: linux, struct, linked-list

I am trying to write an abstract data type to represent sets of integer items using linked lists. I am getting a segmentation fault (linux) or program crashing (windows) and can't understand whats wrong with my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct linkedListElement{
    int data;
    struct linkedListElement * next;
        };

struct linkedListSet {

    struct linkedListElement * header;
    struct linkedListElement * current;
    struct linkedListElement * temp;



         };

struct linkedListSet * createdSet (){

struct linkedListSet * newSet = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedListSet));

newSet->header->data = 0;
newSet->header->next = NULL;

return newSet;

                 };


int main(){
//create set
    struct linkedListSet * firstSet = createdSet();


return (0);
}
```

Comment: Which specific lines of code aren't working here? (I'm just curious, since it's not mentioned here and it might be useful to know this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here..

```
struct linkedListSet * createdSet (){

    struct linkedListSet * newSet = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedListSet));

    // newSet->header is just a pointer - doesn't point to anything valid!
    newSet->header->data = 0;
    newSet->header->next = NULL;

    return newSet;

};
```

You need to ensure the pointers are valid as well.  You may do something like:

```
newSet->header = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedListElement));
```

Comment: Ok thank you - I will try allocate space for and initialise a linkedListElement that is pointed to by header.

Answer (score 0):

You have a created an uninitialized linkedListSet then dereference pointers data and next. These do not point to any memory. You need to allocate a linkedListElement before using it. The correct initialization is:

```
struct linkedListSet * createSet ()
{
    struct linkedListSet * newSet = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedListSet));
    newSet->header = NULL;
    newSet->current = NULL;
    newSet->temp = NULL;
    return newSet;
};
```

Comment: Great - That makes sense. Thank you for taking the time to write this code